# why can't I cast or receive shadows in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm pretty new to this and I'm trying to create lightning and shadows on the objects I just made. As you can see on the picture of the result bellow none of them actually cast or recieve shadows.
I've already enable shadow mapping for the renderer, and also enabled shadow casting and receiving for all of my objects. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Three.js Object Tester</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<script type="module">
    import * as THREE from './js-r119/build/three.module.js';
    import { TrackballControls } from './js-r119/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls.js';

    var WIDTH, HEIGHT, aspectRatio;
    var renderer;
    var scene, camera;
    var controls;
    var mesh;

    init();
    animate();
    function init() {
        HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
        aspectRatio = WIDTH / HEIGHT;

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        renderer.setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
        renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000 );
        renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 1000 );
        camera.position.set( 0, 40, 80 );
        camera.lookAt( scene.position );

        var light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xF5F5F3 ); //ambiens fény

        scene.add( light );

        var floorgeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 150, 150, 1, 1 );
        var floormaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xFFFFFF, wireframe: false } );
        var floor = new THREE.Mesh( floorgeometry, floormaterial );
        floor.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        floor.rotation.x = 1.57;
        floor.position.z = 0;
        floor.position.x = 0;
        floor.position.y = -42.5;
        floor.receiveShadow = true;
        floor.castShadow = true;
        scene.add( floor );


        var vertgeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 20, 45, 20);
        var vertmaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xD5D8DC, wireframe: false } );
        var vert = new THREE.Mesh( vertgeometry, vertmaterial );
        vert.castShadow = true;
        vert.receiveShadow = true;
        vert.rotation.z = 0;
        vert.rotation.x = 0;
        vert.rotation.y = 0;
        vert.position.z = 0;
        vert.position.x = 0;
        vert.position.y = -20;


        var horgeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 20, 40, 20);
        var hormaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xD5D8DC, wireframe: false } );
        var hor = new THREE.Mesh( horgeometry, hormaterial );
        hor.castShadow = true;
        hor.position.z = 0;
        hor.position.y = -32.5;
        hor.position.x = 30;
        hor.rotation.z = 1.57;
        hor.rotation.x = 0;
        hor.rotation.y = 0;

        scene.add( hor );

        var roofgeometry = new THREE.ConeGeometry( 14.142, 40, 4);

        var roofmaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xF98E76, wireframe: false } );
        var roof = new THREE.Mesh( roofgeometry, roofmaterial );
        roof.castShadow = true;
        roof.position.z = 0;
        roof.position.y = 22.5;
        roof.position.x = 0;
        roof.rotation.z = 0;
        roof.rotation.x = 0;
        roof.rotation.y = 0.775;

        scene.add( roof );

        scene.add( vert );

        var lampgeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 25, 2);
        var lampmaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x566573, wireframe: false } );
        var lamp = new THREE.Mesh( lampgeometry, lampmaterial );
        lamp.castShadow = true;
        lamp.rotation.z = 0;
        lamp.rotation.y = 0;
        lamp.position.z = 0;
        lamp.position.x = -60;
        lamp.position.y = -30;

        var spotgeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 3, 3, 3);
        var spotmaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xF6F50B, wireframe: false } );
        var spot = new THREE.Mesh( spotgeometry, spotmaterial );
        spot.position.z = 0;
        spot.position.y = -17.5;
        spot.position.x = -60;

        scene.add( lamp );
        scene.add( spot );

        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200, 20, 20);
        var appearence = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial ({
            color: 0xa2a7a9,
            wireframe: false
        });

        var objgeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(8,12,8);
        var objmaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x1C1C03, wireframe: false});
        var obj = new THREE.Mesh(objgeometry, objmaterial);
        obj.castShadow = true;
        obj.receiveShadow = true;
        obj.position.z = 0;
        obj.position.x = -40;
        obj.position.y = -36.5;
        scene.add(obj);



        var sLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xF6F50B, 3 ); // spotfény segédgeometriával
        sLight.position.set( -60, -17.5, 0 );
        sLight.castShadow = true;
        sLight.distance = 100;
        sLight.target = obj;
        sLight.castShadow = true;
        sLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
        sLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;

        scene.add( sLight );

        var spotLightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper( sLight );
        scene.add( spotLightHelper );


        window.addEventListener( 'resize', handleWindowResize, false );



        controls = new TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
        controls.panSpeed = 1.0;
    }

    function handleWindowResize() {
        HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
        console.log( 'WIDTH=' + WIDTH + '; HEIGHT=' + HEIGHT );
        renderer.setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
        aspectRatio = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
        camera.aspect = aspectRatio;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        render();
    }

    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        controls.update();

        render();
    }

    function render() {
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place a spot light in your scene, you have to ensure that no shadow casting meshes block the emissions of the lights. This happens in your app since the light is place "inside" the `lamp` mesh. Update code:

```js
var WIDTH, HEIGHT, aspectRatio;
var renderer;
var scene, camera;
var controls;
var mesh, spotLightHelper;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
  WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
  aspectRatio = WIDTH / HEIGHT;

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(0, 40, 80);
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xF5F5F3, 0.4); //ambiens fény

  scene.add(light);

  var floorgeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(150, 150, 1, 1);
  var floormaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xFFFFFF,
    wireframe: false
  });
  var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorgeometry, floormaterial);
  //floor.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
  floor.rotation.x = -Math.PI * 0.5;
  floor.position.z = 0;
  floor.position.x = 0;
  floor.position.y = -42.5;
  floor.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(floor);


  var vertgeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 45, 20);
  var vertmaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xD5D8DC,
    wireframe: false
  });
  var vert = new THREE.Mesh(vertgeometry, vertmaterial);
  vert.castShadow = true;
  vert.receiveShadow = true;
  vert.rotation.z = 0;
  vert.rotation.x = 0;
  vert.rotation.y = 0;
  vert.position.z = 0;
  vert.position.x = 0;
  vert.position.y = -20;


  var horgeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 40, 20);
  var hormaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xD5D8DC,
    wireframe: false
  });
  var hor = new THREE.Mesh(horgeometry, hormaterial);
  hor.castShadow = true;
  hor.position.z = 0;
  hor.position.y = -32.5;
  hor.position.x = 30;
  hor.rotation.z = 1.57;
  hor.rotation.x = 0;
  hor.rotation.y = 0;

  scene.add(hor);

  var roofgeometry = new THREE.ConeGeometry(14.142, 40, 4);

  var roofmaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xF98E76,
    wireframe: false
  });
  var roof = new THREE.Mesh(roofgeometry, roofmaterial);
  roof.castShadow = true;
  roof.position.z = 0;
  roof.position.y = 22.5;
  roof.position.x = 0;
  roof.rotation.z = 0;
  roof.rotation.x = 0;
  roof.rotation.y = 0.775;

  scene.add(roof);

  scene.add(vert);

  var lampgeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 25, 2);
  var lampmaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x566573,
    wireframe: false
  });
  var lamp = new THREE.Mesh(lampgeometry, lampmaterial);
  lamp.rotation.z = 0;
  lamp.rotation.y = 0;
  lamp.position.z = 0;
  lamp.position.x = -60;
  lamp.position.y = -30;

  var spotgeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3);
  var spotmaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xF6F50B,
    wireframe: false
  });
  var spot = new THREE.Mesh(spotgeometry, spotmaterial);
  spot.position.z = 0;
  spot.position.y = -17.5;
  spot.position.x = -60;

  scene.add(lamp);
  scene.add(spot);

  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 20, 20);
  var appearence = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xa2a7a9,
    wireframe: false
  });

  var objgeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(8, 12, 8);
  var objmaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x1C1C03,
    wireframe: false
  });
  var obj = new THREE.Mesh(objgeometry, objmaterial);
  obj.castShadow = true;
  obj.receiveShadow = true;
  obj.position.z = 0;
  obj.position.x = -40;
  obj.position.y = -36.5;
  scene.add(obj);



  var sLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xF6F50B, 1); // spotfény segédgeometriával
  sLight.position.set(-60, -17.5, 0);
  sLight.castShadow = true;
  sLight.distance = 100;
  sLight.target = obj;
  sLight.angle = Math.PI * 0.2;
  sLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
  sLight.shadow.camera.far = 100;
  sLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
  sLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;

  scene.add(sLight);

  spotLightHelper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(sLight);
  scene.add(spotLightHelper);

  var cameraHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper(sLight.shadow.camera);
  scene.add(cameraHelper)


  window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize, false);

}

function handleWindowResize() {
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
  WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  aspectRatio = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
  camera.aspect = aspectRatio;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  render();
}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  spotLightHelper.update();

  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.js"></script>
```

BTW: When using `SpotLightHelper`, makes sure to update this helper in the animation loop. Besides, `CameraHelper` is useful for debugging the shadow frustum.

Comment: Thanks, it's fine now